# How to Calculate Total Number of Memory in Azure VM's

Tags: azure, powershell-3.0, powershell-v6.0

I have Azure account and I need to know how much memory is installed in all the VM's. For number of Cores, I use below command.

```
>Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location WestUS
```

But how can I get the Memory details?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by memory but check this link maybe can help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-memory

Comment: I WANT THIS:-
Name vCPUs Memory Storage IOPS Premium SSD
VM001 16            64          1060 500        Yes


I GET THE CORES INFORMATION :
PS Azure:\> Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location ' west us 2'

Name                             Current Value Limit  Unit
----                             ------------- -----  ----
Availability Sets                            0  2000 Count
Total Regional vCPUs                         1     4 Count
Virtual Machines                             1 10000 Count
Virtual Machine Scale Sets                   0  2000 Count

Comment: If the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. It would help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just give you an example: How to get installed memory for each VM, and note that if you want to calculate the total number of installed memory for all VMs, just add them one by one.

```
#get all the vms in the resource group, you also can get all the vms in your subscription by removing -ResourceGroupName "xxx"
$vms = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -status

foreach($vm in $vms)
{
  $temp = Get-AzureRmVMSize -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -VMName $vm.name | where{$_.Name -eq $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize}

  #get each vm's installed memory
  $vm_memory = $temp.MemoryInMB

  Write-Output "VM Name: $($vm.name); VM Memory: $vm_memory"

  #if you want to count all the vms' memory, you can write your own logic here
}
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Dear Ivan, 
Thanks for your reply. can you plz confirm how to run this script.

Comment: You're welcome, and please let me if any issue about it. and if it works, please help mark as answer. thanks.

Comment: @MalikAdeelImtiaz, you can copy them into your powershell prompt(one time copy one line), or you can open your powershell ISE, and copy the code into powershell ISE, and click run to run it.

Comment: I have not checked yet...Let me check and will get back to you in a day.

Comment: Please see below image.

Comment: Get-AzureRmVM : The term 'Get-AzureRmVM' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:8
+ $vms = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -status
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureRmVM:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: 2 things need confirm: 1. in powershell prompt, type "get-help Get-AzureRmVM", and let me know if it can work well. 2. For -ResourceGroupName "xxx", you should replace the "xxx" with your own resource group name.